# Remove first instance of a term in string - case insensitive

Tags: php

I have:

```
$string = 'Hello x World hello';
```

And I want to remove the first instance of a term that is **case insensitive**.

For example, I have:

```
$term = 'hello';
```

And I want to match it with `$string`, so we end up with:

```
$string = ' x World hello';
```

### What I've done so far

I am *nearly* there! I can replace the first instance of a term with:

```
function str_replace_once($str_pattern, $str_replacement, $string){

    if (strpos($string, $str_pattern) !== false){
        $occurrence = strpos($string, $str_pattern);
        return substr_replace($string, $str_replacement, strpos($string, $str_pattern), strlen($str_pattern));
    }

    return $string;
}
```

But it is *not* case insensitive, see [ideone](https://ideone.com/h15yX9). How can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, just replace `strpos` with `stripos`... (with a few minor tweaks)...

```
function str_replace_once($str_pattern, $str_replacement, $string){
    $pos = stripos($string, $str_pattern);
    if ($pos !== false){
        return substr_replace($string, $str_replacement, $pos, strlen($str_pattern));
    }
    
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish `str_ireplace` had a limit, it would be better.  But `preg_replace` has a limit.  Use the `i` modifier for case-insensitive:

```
$string = preg_replace("/$term/i", "", $string, 1);
```

Also note that there is a [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) which is case-insensitive `strpos` which you can use in your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stripos`(case-insensitive) and `substr`

```
function str_replace_first($str, $search, $replace)
{
    $index = stripos($str, $search);
    return $index === false ? $str : substr($str, 0, $index) . $replace . substr($str, $index + strlen($search));
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$string = 'Hello x World hello';
echo str_replace_first($string,'Hello', '');
```